# How to make a method similar to on / off button using if-else

Tags: android, if-statement, button, onclick, chronometer

I try to put the control of the chronometer on the button, for start and stop. Tried to implement it, but the result is not the same, help with the advice?

```
 public void onStartClick(View view){
    mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    if(mButton.isPressed()==false){
        mChronometer.start();}else{
        mChronometer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would be easiest is my opinion:

```
 boolean mIsOn = false;
 public void onStartClick(View view){
   mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
   if(!mIsOn){
     mChronometer.start();
   }
   else{
     mChronometer.stop();

   }
   mIsOn = !mIsOn;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onClick(View view){
   if(mButton.getTag().equals("ON")){
      mButton.setTag("ON");
      mChronometer.start().
   }else{
      mChronometer.stop();
      mButton.setTag("OFF");
   }
}
```